# Available ports for brokers in MapR cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, mapr

I have written some program which use two brokers to send the messages..as follow:

```
val kafkaBrokers = "172.16.50.64:9092,172.16.50.65:9093"
```

The IPs are the address of the cluster nodes but I get

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
org.apache.spark.SparkException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException..
```

I wanted to know which ports I can use for a MapR cluster..

Comment: Are you trying to talk to a real kafka broker or are you trying to talk to a MapR stream?

Comment: any port above 1024 should be run fine without super user privileges. your problem might have to do with something else, can you provide more detail of what you're trying to do?